# How to display spinner when i checking host on online?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

sorry for my english. I have 60 hosts like
**http://10.89.0.243/qwer.nsf/RIJP?WSDL**
I'm need to check each host for down. This should be not task (i'm need to check this 60 hosts 3 times in day for example and this site will use 2 people).
With checking - all good - if i get not Net::HTTPSuccess then i print, for example, label with value NO, that indicates that this host is down, but i have 60 host and while each host checking my page don't loading until all hosts are checked.

I want to display this page instantly and when each host is checking i'm need to display spinner logo or simple text like 'checking...' or 'loading...'. How to do this? I'm need to use java script in rails?

ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
Rails 5.2.3

Comment: thanks, i think this is right direction =) I will try ajax technology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep - you'll likely want to load the page with a holding status / the spinner then use AJAX to fetch the websites' statuses.

Have a read of [this guide](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) for the very basics - hope this helps point you in the right direction :)

You could then cache these results until you need to check again.